# Enable AWS SDK Service client metrics in C++

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-cpp

I want to enable aws service client metrics in aws sdk c++ , In java v2 we have the option to enable aws sdk service clients metrics like (Pending connection, Max connection) details please refer this page - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/metrics-list.html.

But I don't find any details about enable sdk service client metrics for c++. where can i find the details to enable sdk metrics in aws sdk c++.

Comment: Do you refer to this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/sdk-metrics.html

Comment: @OmarRosadio it's requires to install cloudwatch agent in my ECS EC2 instance but we are not allow to install cloudwatch agent in our ec2. I am looking to generate aws sdk service clients metrics with out install cloudwatch agent. I did in Java just to add the cloudwatch publisher jar no need to install cloudwatch agent. But c++ aws sdk not provide the option without install cloudwatch agent.